# vb.net making a correct form to insert into access DB

Tags: vb.net, insert

I have a DB table in Access 2010 named `Clienti` with columns:

- `nume` (text)
- `prenume` ( text )
- `cnp` (number)
- `varsta` ( number )
- `adresa` (text)
- `localitate` (text)
- `data` (date)
- `stare` civila (text)
- `numarcopii` (number)
- `venit` ( number)
- `tipcreditales` (text)
- `rezultat` (text)

I've made a form in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2013 by which I want to insert data into the `Clienti` table.

My problems are:

1. For `data` I use date/time picker. Is there any way I can convert it to date? When I try to insert it, VB says that date/time picker can not be converted to date.
2. For `stare civila` I want a combobox to be used with 3 items. How can I convert those 3 items in strings? ( the items are manually introduced by me ).
3. For `tipcreditales` as well I want to use a combobox, so same question as above can be applied.

Code used is:

```
    Convert.ToInt32(cnptxt.Text)
    Convert.ToInt32(numarcopiitxt.Text)

    Dim cnpp As Integer
    cnpp = Val(cnptxt.Text)
    Dim nrcopii As Integer
    nrcopii = Val(numarcopiitxt.Text)

    Dim nume As String

    Dim prenume As String
    Dim cnp As Integer
    Dim varsta As Integer
    Dim adresa As String
    Dim localitate As String
    Dim starecivila As String
    Dim numarcopii As Integer
    Dim data As Date = datatxt.Value.Date
    Dim venit As Integer
    Dim tipcreditales As String
    Dim rezultat As String

    nume = numetxt.Text
    prenume = prenumetxt.Text
    cnp = cnpp
    varsta = varstatxt.Text
    adresa = adresatxt.Text
    localitate = localitatetxt.Text
    starecivila = starecivilatxt.Text
    numarcopii = numarcopiitxt.Text
    tipcreditales = ComboBox1
    rezultat = rezultattxt.Text

    If Me.ClientiTableAdapter.InsertQueryClienti(nume, prenume, cnp, varsta, adresa, localitate, starecivila, numarcopii, tipcreditales, rezultat) Then
        MsgBox("Adaugat cu succes in baza de date!")
    End If
```

When trying to run the app it says:

> 1  Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' cannot be converted to 'String'.  D:\Test\incercare2\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\Form3.vb 60  25  WindowsApplication2
>
> 2  Argument not specified for parameter 'rezultat' of 'Public Overridable Overloads Function InsertQueryClienti(nume As String, prenume As String, cnp As Integer?, varsta As Integer?, adresa As String, localitate As String, data As Date?, stare_civila As String, numarcopii As Integer?, venit As String, tipcreditales As String, rezultat As String) As Integer'.  D:\Test\incercare2\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\Form3.vb 62  12  WindowsApplication2
>
> 3  Argument not specified for parameter 'tipcreditales' of 'Public Overridable Overloads Function InsertQueryClienti(nume As String, prenume As String, cnp As Integer?, varsta As Integer?, adresa As String, localitate As String, data As Date?, stare_civila As String, numarcopii As Integer?, venit As String, tipcreditales As String, rezultat As String) As Integer'. D:\Test\incercare2\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\Form3.vb 62  12  WindowsApplication2

Code for InsertQueryClienti is

```
`Public Overridable Overloads Function InsertQueryClienti(
ByVal nume As String
ByVal prenume As String 
ByVal cnp As Global.System.Nullable(Of Integer)
ByVal varsta As Global.System.Nullable(Of Integer), 
ByVal adresa As String,
ByVal localitate As String,
ByVal data As Global.System.Nullable(Of Date)
ByVal stare_civila As String,
ByVal numarcopii As Global.System.Nullable(Of Integer),
ByVal venit As String, 
ByVal tipcreditales As String,
ByVal rezultat As String) As Integer`
```

Comment: `myDateTimePicker.Value` will return the selected date for the CBOs just user `myCombo.Items(n)` where n is a value from 0 to  `myCombo.Items.Count-1`.  Know that SO rather frowns on multiple questions per post and no code showing what you tried

Comment: added code and errors i'm getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's how you get the DateTimePicker value:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Public Sub New()
   ' Create a new DateTimePicker 
   Dim dateTimePicker1 As New DateTimePicker()
   Controls.AddRange(New Control() {dateTimePicker1})
   MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString())

   dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
   MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString())
End Sub 'New
```

[Here's how you get the ComboBox value:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Private Sub showSelectedButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim selectedIndex As Integer
    selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex
    Dim selectedItem As Object
    selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem

    MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " & selectedItem.ToString() & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbCrLf & _
                        "Index: " & selectedIndex.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: i've added the code and errors i'm getting. Could you take a look over it?

Comment: Try changing `tipcreditales = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks very much. It solved the combobox problem. I only have now the 2 errors about argument not specified for parameter rezultat and tipcreditales.

Comment: That's because in `InsertQueryClienti` you are only passing in `10` parameters, but it is expecting `12`.

Comment: You are right, i was forgetting to add 2 fields in the query. only one error left: Value of type 'date' can not be converted to 'Integer?'. How can i solve this one? It's surelly from my definition  Dim data As Date = datatxt.Value.Date

Comment: Is `datatxt` your `DateTimePicker`? If so, just do `Dim data As Date = datatxt.Value`.

Comment: I did that already. Now it won't start because an error from the Comboboxes. I've populated them by right click on the combobox and add items. Now when i try to run the application if says that necasatorit(one of the items i've added ) can not be converted to date. What the hell did i do?

Comment: 1) Does `datatxt` actually have a value? 2) `Dim data As Date = datatxt.Value.Date` is not right. Remove the `.Date` off of `datatxt.Value`.

Comment: datatxt is the name i've given to the DateTimePicker

Comment: The only remaining problem is with the comboboxes. when i select any item from them it returns the error " Conversion from string "necasatorit" to type 'Date' is not valid. Where could the problem be?

Comment: Most likely you have the parameters in the wrong order when calling `InsertQueryClienti`.  Check them and make sure all the data types match.

Comment: i finally made it. thank you so much dude, you're the real MVP.